# deleting HBITMAP causes an access violation at runtime

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, graphics, gdi+

I have the following code to take a screenshot of a window, and get the colour of a specific pixel in it:

```
void ProcessScreenshot(HWND hwnd){

HDC WinDC;
HDC CopyDC;
HBITMAP hBitmap;
RECT rt;

GetClientRect (hwnd, &rt);
WinDC = GetDC (hwnd);
CopyDC = CreateCompatibleDC (WinDC);

//Create a bitmap compatible with the DC
hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap (WinDC,
    rt.right - rt.left, //width
    rt.bottom - rt.top);//height

SelectObject (CopyDC, hBitmap);

BitBlt (CopyDC,   //destination
    0,0,
    rt.right - rt.left, //width
    rt.bottom - rt.top, //height
    WinDC,    //source
    0, 0,
    SRCCOPY);       

COLORREF col = ::GetPixel(CopyDC,145,293);

// Do some stuff with the pixel colour.... 

delete hBitmap;

ReleaseDC(hwnd, WinDC);
ReleaseDC(hwnd, CopyDC);

}
```

the line 'delete hBitmap;' causes a runtime error: an access violation. I guess I can't just delete it like that?

Because bitmaps take up a lot of space, if I don't get rid of it I will end up with a huge memory leak. My question is: Does releasing the DC the HBITMAP is from deal with this, or does it stick around even after I have released the DC? If the later is the case, how do I correctly get rid of the HBITMAP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must destroy GDI objects with [`DeleteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539%28VS.85%29.aspx), not `delete`. The latter is only used to free objects allocated using `new`.

Answer (score 3):

`delete` should only be used to deallocate things allocated via `new`.

`HBITMAP` is a bitmap handle and you need to release the associated object using the GDI function `DeleteObject`.

Strictly, you should save the result of `SelectObject` from when you selected the bitmap into the device context and pass that to another call to `SelectObject` to ensure that the bitmap is not in use by the device context when you call `DeleteObject`. Things often work if you don't do this, especially if you're about to release the device context anyway but it is safest to do so.